# Why this reference changed without been assigned new value?

Tags: ocaml, mutability

I'm using ocaml 4.10.0 and have a function defined like this:

```
type t = (string * bool) list

let test (t:t) : bool * (string * bool) list =
  match t with
  | [] -> (true,[])
  | (s,b)::[] -> (true,t)
  | _ ->
     let rb = ref true in
     let rl = ref t in
     let rec func (t':t) : unit = 
        match t' with
        | [] -> ()
        | (s,b)::tl -> 
           List.iter(
              fun (s',b') -> 
                 if ((s=s') && (b<>b')) then 
                    rb := false;
                    rl := [(s,b);(s',b')]
           ) tl;
           if (!rb<>false) then func tl;
     in func t; 
     (!rb,!rl)
```

This function should test a list of (string * bool) and return (true,original list) if no inconsistent (string * bool) pairs, otherwise (false,inconsistent pairs).

For example:

> `test [("a",true);("b",false);("a",true)]`  should return
> `(true,[("a",true);("b",false);("a",true)])`

> `test [("a",false);("b",false);("a",true)]`  should return
> `(false,[("a",false);("a",true)])`

However the function I have now is partially wrong, which will return:

> `test [("a",true);("b",false);("a",true)]` returns
> `(true,[("b",false);("a",true)])`

> `test [("a",false);("b",false);("a",true)]` returns
> `(false,[("a",false);("a",true)])`

I can't figure out why `rl` will change while the if statement isn't called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have this:

```
if ((s=s') && (b<>b')) then 
   rb := false;
   rl := [(s,b);(s',b')]
```

But your indentation is misleading. The `then` only controls one following expression. In other words, the third line here is always executed.

You can use `begin/end` (or parentheses) to group both expressions inside the `then`:

```
if ((s=s') && (b<>b')) then
   begin
   rb := false;
   rl := [(s,b);(s',b')]
   end
```

This is a reason that some people suggest you use a system that indents your code automatically. You're less likely to end up with misleading indentations that way.

Comment: Put another way, what you are saying is that `if` has higher [operator precedence](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/expr.html#ss%3Aprecedence-and-associativity) than `;`

Comment: `if` isn't really an operator in the usual sense since it's always paired with `then`. But this is not a bad way to look at the situation. Things are the same in many languages, for what it's worth. E.g., in C, C++, Java, etc: `if (x) f (); g();` The function `g()` will always be called.